# Error Creating Control - Cannot find web project item

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web

I'm getting this error:
Error Creating Control - Label1
Cannot find web project item 'http://localhost:61952/WebSite/Default.aspx'.

(It's a Visual Studio 2010 Website.)

Can't view Labels, User Controls, nothing in design view... Can't drag and drop controls from the tool box either...

I have no idea what caused this problem...

Any hints?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just to get me going with the design mode...

Well, I have a visual studio solution, with projects and class libraries... and my website which I described as having the problem. However, this problem seems to only occur when I'm trying to view the website's pages (in design view), after opening the solution. I tried opening just the website (File -> Open Web Site), and in that case, I am able to use the design view with no problems...

(Adding a new website to my solution also works, only my existent website doesn't work.)

So, solution for the meantime: having two VS opened, one with MySolution/WebSite/, the other with MySolution/CompleteSolution.sln. I do the design stuff in the first and the programming in the second...

Answer (score 0):

Just now I found the solution, just do Unload Project and load it again to existing solution, right now at the time you open the website, it will be fixed :)